# Problem in BindingAdapter with attibute enum of object

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having problem in my `BindingAdapter` when I use an `Enum` type attribute. When I use an Int the problem does not happen.

My **BindingAdapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:setImage")
fun ImageView.setImage(transactionType: TransactionType) {
    when (transactionType) {
        TransactionType.EXPENSE -> this.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_transaction_expense)
        TransactionType.REVENUE -> this.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_transaction_revenue)
    }
}
```

My **Enum**

```
enum class TransactionType {
    REVENUE,
    EXPENSE
}
```

My Object

```
class Transaction(
    val description: String,
    val date: Date,
    val value: Double,
    val transactionType: TransactionType
)
```

My Layout

```
...
<data>
        <variable name="transaction" type="com.paulobressan.financas.model.Transaction"/>
</data>

...

<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_transaction_expense"
                    android:id="@id/image_item"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                    app:setImage="@{transaction.transactionType}"
            />
```

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.paulobressan.financas.model.Transaction.transactionType file:/home/paulo/data/projects/Financas2/app/src/main/res/layout/item_transaction.xml loc:35:36 - 35:62 ****\ data binding error ****
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you connect your model with databinding model. In ViewHolder for RecyclerView item or in onCreate() in your Activity / Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I have this class.

```
class TransactionAdapter(private val transaction: List<Transaction>, private val context: Context) :
    Adapter<TransactionAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemTransactionBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.item_transaction, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return transaction.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val transaction = transaction[position]
        holder.bindView(transaction)
    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemTransactionBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bindView(transaction: Transaction) {
            binding.transaction = transaction
        }
    }
}
```

My Activity

```
class TransactionsActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun layoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_transactions
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val recyclerView = lista_transacoes_recyclerview
        recyclerView.adapter = TransactionAdapter(transactions(), this)

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    }
}
```